# NodeJS daemon not starting at startup on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, debian, daemon

I have created a little daemon that starts my nodejs API as a service using `forever`.

Now that the service starts and stops without any problems, I want to make it start when the raspberry pi turns on. My raspberry pi is running on `Raspbian`.

I've placed the service in the `/etc/init.d/` folder and executed `update-rc.d myServiceName defaults` but it doesn't start the service after booting...

Can you help me? There's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules

case "$1" in
  start)
  exec forever --spinSleepTime 10000 --sourceDir=/var/domothink -p /var/run/forever start dist/server.js
  ;;

  stop)
  exec forever stop --sourceDir=/var/domothink dist/server.js
  ;;

  status)
  # TODO
  ;;

  default)
  # TODO
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Note that init may not have the same $PATH you have for you account so it may not find `forever`. That's why people tend to put absolute paths in init scripts. Try `/whatever/path/to/forever` instead of `forever`

Comment: But when I start the service manualy it works well. without the absolute path. I'll try your solution, to put the abolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution for creating a nodejs service on `Debian` / `Raspbian`.

I installed the `forever-service` package with npm and create the service with this tool.

It's a really good solution and it works really good: https://github.com/zapty/forever-service